# How to compare .wav specimen in delphi?

Tags: delphi, audio, wav, pcm, sound-recognition

I would like to start studying the `.wav` specimen by comparing two files. like returning a result of duration, accent, pronunciation in percentage. etc. or any code that comparing/analyzing the `.wav`.

Comment: Thanx for editing @Andrew Grimm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you think about using Fourier transform? http://www.lohninger.com/fourier.html

Answer (score 0):

For analyzing, processing or appling effects to sound files [SOX - Sound eXchange](http://sox.sourceforge.net/) is wonderful.